# How to call repository service in main class and use main arguments?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

in my spring boot application I'm using main arguments to pass variables and need to call a method to save an object into database based on some code in main class.

I'm using main class like that:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainClass {

    @Autowired
    private RecordingService recordingService;

    public MainClass(String arg1, String arg2) {
        this.setArg1(arg1);
        this.setArg2(arg2);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String ip = null;
        String op = null;

        if (args != null & args.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-ip")) {
                    ip = args[i + 1].trim();
                } else if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-op")) {
                    op = args[i + 1].trim();
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

        if (ip == null || op == null) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input or output path.");
        } else {
            MainClass reader = new MainClass(ip, op);
            Recording recording = new Recording();
            .
            .
            some code...
            .
            .
            this.recordingService.insertIntoDB(recording);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is service class:

```
@Service
public class RecordingService {

    @Autowired
    private RecordingRepository recordingRepository;

    public RecordingService() {
    }

    public void insertToDatabase(Recording recording) {
        try {
            Recording recording = new Recording();
            this.recordingRepository.save(recording);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

When I run this code I get *NullPointerException*, What is the mistake in this code?

Comment: Can you paste stacktrace with NullPointerException?

Comment: @pholak it just shows that ```recordingService``` is null

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the main method without Spring so Spring won't create RecordingService. It can be changed using [CommandLineRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainClass implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private RecordingService recordingService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        //your main code here
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives me nullPointerException, the problem is that I need to use MainClass constructor and I think tha I cannot use a constructor with calling repository by ```@AutoWired``` but I cannot think in another way to achieve that

Comment: Is it required to use MainClass constructor? If so, why?