# How to call a persistence method without a HTTP request with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm new on Spring data JPA and I'm having some... newbie problems.

I can't calling a persistence method without annotation *@Controller* or *HTTP requests* with its annotations inside my class. I know that class interface *CommandLineRunner* implements a method *run* but the main code needs to stay inside the method *run*, I want to call another classes and own methods like a facade behaviour.

**Model:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Expense {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String item;
    private float amount;


    public Expense () {
        
    }
    
    public Expense(String item, float amount) {
        this.item = item;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    /* Getters and setters */

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Expense{" + "id=" + id + ", item=" + item + ", amount=" + amount + '}';
    }
```

**Interface Repository**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ExpenseRepository extends JpaRepository<Expense, Long>{
    
    public List<Expense> findByItem (String item);
    
    @Query("SELECT e FROM Expense e WHERE e.amount >= :amount")
    public List<Expense> listItemsWithPriceOver(@Param("amount") float amount);
    
}
```

**Persistence class:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class ExpansePersistence {

    @Autowired
    private ExpenseRepository repository;

    public void expensePersistence() {
        repository.save(new Expense("tomato", 10));
        repository.save(new Expense("banana", 6));
        repository.save(new Expense("apple", 12));
        
        Iterable<Expense> iterator = repository.findAll();

        System.out.println("List all: ");
        iterator.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item.toString()));
    }
    
}
```

**Main method**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        new ExpensePersistence().expensePersistence();
    }

}
```

There is a similar thread ([How to call repository service in main class and use main arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73171410/how-to-call-repository-service-in-main-class-and-use-main-arguments)) here where the user had the same problem and same output error, but the answer only solved the *run *method using the interface *CommandLineRunner* but coding inside the run method. I want to call another methods.

The running code generates the message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.demo.ExpenseRepository.findAll()" because "this.repository" is null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because your instance of `ExpansePersistence` class doesn't have an injected instance of `ExpenseRepository` class - Spring IoC container can't do that.
You should declare bean of `ExpansePersistence` class (for example using `@Service` annotation) and it will be better to make it implements `CommandLineRunner`. Something like that:

```
@Service
public class ExpansePersistence implements CommandLineRunner {

    ...

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        expensePersistence();
    }
}
```

Then `ExpansePersistence` and `ExpenseRepository` both will be controlled by Spring IoC and bean injection will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided `TestPersistence` is a unit test. That means that it doesn't recognize annotations such as `@Autowired` (since it has not spring context). You need an `@SpringBootTest` to be able to autowire beans (in your case the repository). In this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing) you can find an example that tests a repository using `@SpringBootTest`.

Good luck!